# How can I slide up previous text and slide down present text with slider slid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to slide up previous slide's sidebar text, and slide down present slide's sidebar text with slider images slid. Here I want to slideup slide-content- when images slid in the slider. html and script are as following:

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
 interval: 5000
});

$('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

//Handles the carousel thumbnails
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
 var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
 var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
 var id = parseInt(id);
 $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
});

// When the carousel slides, auto update the text
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e){
 $(this).html($('#slide-content-').html());
 var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
 $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Slider -->
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12" id="slider">
      <!-- Top part of the slider -->
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8" id="carousel-bounding-box">
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="active item" style="float:left" data-slide-number="0"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&amp;text=one"></div>
              <div class="item" style="float:left" data-slide-number="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&amp;text=two"></div>
              <div class="item" style="float:left" data-slide-number="2"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&amp;text=three"></div>
             </div>
            <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id="carousel-text"></div>
        
        <div style="display: none;" id="slide-content">
          <div id="slide-content-0">
            <h2>Slider One</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
            <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
          </div>
          <div id="slide-content-1">
            <h2>Slider Two</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
            <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
          </div>
          <div id="slide-content-2">
            <h2>Slider Three</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
            <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!--/Slider-->
</div>
```

Comment: I really could not understand what you want to do and what is your question! Please create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and explain your problem/request with example in that fiddle

Comment: Sorry, I could not create jsfiddle link. But I have bootply link. Here is the 
[link](http://www.bootply.com/BXptYrioy1).

Here I want to add a effect on the text of the right side. When slider slid to next image, text will slide up and next text will slide down.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. here is a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehsant/gt8682e7/1/). In plain _jQuery_ you have limited number of easing. but if you use _jQuery UI_, then you have more number of them. Right now in this example I'm using _swing_ easing to show and hide the _carousel-text_. If it's what you want, then I can post it as an answer

Comment: I'll edit it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also I think instead of `slid` event for _carousel_ which waits till the slide transition is completed and then fires, it's better for you to use `slide` event that fires immediately when the _slide instance method is invoked._